# MySQL fetch results form top to bottom

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query for MySQL in which I want to fetch results from the bottom to the top of the table. I considered `ORDER` BY but I'm looking for perhaps something that's faster/more efficient. I just want to know if there's something built-in that makes the search from bottom (i.e. most recent) to top (oldest).

My database is large, so I think `ORDER BY` may be pretty slow. Thanks in advance!

Comment: add an index for the columns that you are ordering by

Comment: @chuex I do have an index that I'm ordering by. I considered that method, and I'm simply asking if there's a better one.

Comment: It will help if you post your existing query, table structure, and any query plans. As it written, it will be difficult to give an answer.

Comment: You might want to create a VIEW, this is a cached result of your query; see http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views.aspx

Answer (score 1):

i recommended using ORDER BY column_name DESC clause for more faster than sorting from it's php program.

Answer (score 0):

It will almost certainly be more efficient to sort the data in the database. Databases are designed to deal with large data volumes. And there are various optimizations available to the database that would not be available to the middle tier. If you plan on writing a hyper-efficient sort routine in the middle tier that takes advantage of information that you have about your data that the database doesn't (i.e. farming the data out to a cluster of dozens of middle tier machines so that the sort never spills to disk, taking advantage of the fact that your data is mostly ordered to choose an algorithm that wouldn't normally be particularly efficient), you can probably beat the database's sort speed. But that tends to be rare.

Depending on the query, for example, the database optimizer may choose a query plan that returns the data in order without performing a sort. For example, the database knows that the data in an index is sorted so it may choose to do an index scan to return the data in order without ever having to materialize and sort the entire result set. If it does have to materialized the entire result, it only needs the columns you are sorting by and some sort of row identifier (i.e. a ROWID in Oracle) rather than sorting an entire row of data like a naive middle tier implementation is likely to do. For example, if you have a composite index on (col1, col2) and you decide to sort on UPPER(col2), LOWER(col1), the database could read the col1 & col2 values from the index, sort the row identifiers, and then go fetch the data from the table. Of course, the database doesn't have to do this-- the optimizer will take into account the cost of doing a sort against the cost of fetching the data from the table or from the various indexes. The database may well conclude that the most efficient approach is to do a table scan, read the entire row into memory, and sort it. It may conclude that leveraging an index results in more I/O to fetch the data but makes up for it by reducing or eliminating the sort costs.